# Giving edges arc shape

Tags: edges

I have this mesh(pic1) and i want give arc on sides(pic2) except bottom side. I tried bewel(CTRL+B) but some edges messed up(pic3). Then i added a line between edge lines and applied ALT+S but for sure it scales bottom too. So do you have any practic idea for it ?

pic1
[image]

pic2
[image]

pic3
[image]

Comment: Use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com/) that follows your shape edgeflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whats going on is because of your model's many edges regular old Bevel won't work. So what you need to do is to go into edge mode and only select the outer most edges, as shown in the first picture. Now when you bevel it shouldn't glitch out with with weird geometry.

Lastly on the second picture I circled in red where two edges  were getting too close together and would cause a problem if beveled a bit more. Essentially watch out for overlapping edges when beveling.

Hope this helps!

[image: First Image not beveled]
[image: Second Image beveled]

(Also having all those edges is a good thing it means you don't have any N-gons, if you didn't know N-gons are any faces with more then 4 edges. N-gons can cause problems with lighting and texturing and sometimes modeling).

Comment: Actually i observed your geometry and put the edge in pic1 on my geometry too. Then i tried again and it seemed to fix problem! looks better now(pic2). Thank you :) pic1:https://prnt.sc/gwgi8l, pic2: https://prnt.sc/gwggnr

Comment: Also i have never heard about N-gons, so i will give it a search too :)